# parent menu item doesn't react to text color

Tags: css

When a child menu item is active its parent menu should look the same. However, I don't know why, the parent item reacts only to `background-color: #83bf17` but not to `color: #6B4A38;`.

Live example: http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/projekt/kama/lecznica/

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.current-menu-parent {
    color: #6B4A38;
    background-color: #83bf17;   
}
```

Edit
Sorry, forgot to mention that `!important` doesn't work.

Comment: Its because you have color attribute in the class .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a. Have you tried with !important. Try to add the color like this   color: #6B4A38 !important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.current-menu-parent > a{
    color:#6b4a38;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important` for `color` like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.current-menu-parent {
    color: #6B4A38 !important;
    background-color: #83bf17;   
}
```

Edit: Try to comment color from the following class

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    /* color: #83bf17;*/
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have a more specific selector which is overriding

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
     color: #83bf17;
     ....;
}
```

so you should delete that in order for the element to inherit the parent's value for the color property

Answer (score 1):

try `.current-menu-parent a {` you have to target `a` if it's to receive color. And to target only direct descendant `a` use `.current-menu-parent > a {` if there's no elements in between (I checked there is no elements in between).

There's another problem beside not targeting `a`, you have too specific selector that overrides color even if `a` is included in selector.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
a.dropdown-toggle {
color: #6B4A38 !important;
}
```